# TFS Description Field - Set Default Text with Formatted HTML

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am customizing the TFS (2012) User Story description field to contain default text.  I'd like to apply formatting to the default text similar to what is possible to text entered after the work item is created.  Primarily bold text, but it would be nice to know how to apply other enhancements as well.

Example Default Text:

**User Story**
As a [Role] I want/can/need to/ [Goal] so that [business value]

**Business Acceptance Criteria**

**Technical Requirements**

**Testable Scenarios**

**UPDATE:  Solution Found**
After much pain attempting to encode the HTML, turns out it was easier than  expected.

```
<b>User Story </b><br/> As a [Role] I want/can/need to/ [Goal] so that [business value] <br/><br/><br/><b>Business Acceptance Criteria</b><br/> <br/><br/><br/><b>Technical Acceptance Criteria</b><br/><br/><br/><br/><b>Testable Scenarios</b><br/>
```

A Few Notes:

- This can be set as a 'Default' rule on the field, a state or a transition
- There is a character limit on this so I wasn't able to add more than shown above.
- Everything must be entered as a single line of text in the rule 'Value' input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter HTML into the process template's Default field, you just have to encode the <> characters as the XML entities &lt; and &gt;. The only limitation is that it will only accept a tiny string (and it can't include newlines, although <br/> commands are fine), so your default text can't hold more than a few words.

Comment: May not need to encode in TFS 2012 / 2013 as the description field is now HTML?

Comment: Ah, possibly not. Glad you found the answer anyway :-)